# In MongoDb, are sub documents references or extensions

Tags: mongodb

Using mongoose you can create a sub document as such:

```
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: "email is required.",
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: "firstName is required."
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: "lastName is required."
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
        type: Date,
        required: "dateOfBirth is required."
    },
    roles: [{
        role: String,
        required: "role is required",
        validate: isValidUserRole
    }],
    address: AddressSchema,
});
```

Address Schema

```
export const AddressSchema = new Schema({
    streetAddress: {
        type: String
    },
    addressLine2: {
        type: String
    },
    city: {
        type: String
    },
    state: {
        type: String
    },
    zipCode: {
        type: String
    },
    country: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

Whenever I save a user, will mongoose create a new user document with nested address data or a user and address and then reference that address document within the user instance?

How would I approach the case of 2 users sharing the same address?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the sample schema of AddressSchema

Comment: I just added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to provide the `AddressSchema` in the `UserSchema` schema.

You can just provide `reference` of `AddressSchema` like the following.

```
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: "email is required.",
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: "firstName is required."
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: "lastName is required."
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
        type: Date,
        required: "dateOfBirth is required."
    },
    roles: [{
        role: String,
        required: "role is required",
        validate: isValidUserRole
    }],
    address: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'AddressSchema',required:true}
});
```

But remember that in order to make this work, 1st you need to create an `Address` data and provide their `_id` in `UserSchema`.

What happens by the above method is,

**AddressSchema's `ObjectId(_id)` works as the REFERENCE in UserSchema. Basically, it acts as a REFERENCE DOCUMENT in UserSchema**

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out by querying your data through `mongo` shell.

When a document contains an embedded document (this is indistinguishable from nested hashes in the shell), the embedded document wholly belongs to the top level document and cannot be included-by-reference into another document.